# Why the formula of the average linear deviation is so not aplicable

Tags: statistics

The formula of the mean square deviation is more "famous" then the formula of the average linear deviation. Why, and whats practical difference?

Comment: Are you talking about the average absolute deviation?  Using mean square deviation may correspond to your loss function, and the regression line is is easier to calculate

Comment: Both measures are frequently used.  The [Gauss-Markov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) is at least one reason to look at squared differences.